# Что в себе содержит Environment?

Tags: java, spring

Добрый день. Какую информацию в себе содержит интерфейс `Environment`? Я так понимаю это интерфейс для работы с `properties`? Откуда он берёт эти `properties`? И как его можно настроить таким образом, что-бы он работал с `*.properties` в моём приложении?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интерфейс [Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) представляет окружение, в котором приложение запущено.

Свойства (properties) - это не только содержимое файлов с соответствующим расширением, но и свойства JVM, переменные окружения операционной системы, параметры сервлета (если приложение запущено в соответствующем контейнере) и многое другое. `Environment` предоставляет к ним ко всем единообразный доступ. Что касается конкретно файлов, ответ зависит от того, как вы хотите эти свойства использовать, как предпочитаете конфигурировать ваше приложение и прочего. Например, местоположение файла свойств можно задать директивой в xml-конфигурации:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

Тогда Spring будет искать файл application.properties в classpath и обеспечит возможность подстановки свойств в xml-конфигурации и аннотациях:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
</bean>
```

Можно задать расположение файла свойств с помощью аннотации, если вы предпочитаете конфигурацию в коде:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig { ... }
```

Можно даже прямым конфигурированием контекста:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
context
  .getEnvironment()
  .getPropertySources()
  .addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource(new ClassPathResource("application.properties")));
```

Кроме доступа к свойствам, `Environment` служит ещё для определение текущего профиля конфигурации и профиля по умолчанию.